# Create cache control for images in php

Tags: php, image, performance, iis, cache-control

I run on a Windows server and want to cache different resources for different time periods: some stuff never changes, and other stuff changes every few weeks.

If I had Apache, I could use .htaccess to set up a list of commands like this (actually, this is what I used last year):

```
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 100 days"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 100 days"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 100 days"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 100 days"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 100 days"
```

But I don't. IIS has nothing that I can see that's so specific, so perhaps I need to do this with PHP.
I've read a whole host of articles, but none give specific advice on how to achieve the same result as the .htaccess solution above.
Ideally, make it page-specific, which is where PHP might come in ... maybe some statements at the top of each page?

Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't been in IIS in a long time, but you should be able to do all of this in web.config [globally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache) or [per-extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/caching/)

Comment: Thank you Chris, but I need the "how" rather than the "whether" ... I'm sure it can be done, but how to do it doesn't seem to be covered anywhere. My preference would be PHP because I can do it on a script-by-script basis, but if it's IIS then OK :)